# What is the real command to know the total real time CPU % status on Linux env and what is the ideal value

Tags: linux, cpu, top, htop

I understood that `top` and `htop` give a lot of info in real-time on the server status. But what really gives me the total CPU of the server? can I rely on the id column from the `top` command:

```
%Cpu(s):  1.9 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.2 id,  5.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
```

For example, from the above example, does that total CPU is 92.2% out of 100%? can we use this command:

```
(top -b -n2 -p 1 | fgrep "Cpu(s)" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix="$prefix" '{ split($1, vs, ","); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub("%", "", v); printf "%s%.1f%%\n", prefix, 100 - v }')
```

or from this link [overall-cpu-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux) where the calculation suggested there is:

```
awk '{u=$2+$4; t=$2+$4+$5; if (NR==1){u1=u; t1=t;} else print ($2+$4-u1) * 100 / (t-t1) "%"; }' \
<(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) <(sleep 1;grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat)
```

or:

```
top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | \
           sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | \
           awk '{print 100 - $1"%"}'
```

or:

```
mpstat | awk '$3 ~ /CPU/ { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /%idle/) field=i } } $3 ~ /all/ { print 100 - $field }'
```

also, what suppose to be the ideal value which we don't want to pass?

Comment: The "id" column in top means % **idle**, not in use. So that machine has the CPUs 92.2% idle at that point.

Comment: *ideal value which we don't want to pass?* It's a percentage, so you can't really get more than 100% CPU busy.

Comment: so which command gives me the total CPU in real-time?

Comment: The question depends a lot of the context. Is that a desktop machine? Is it a laptop and are you worried about heating and power usage? (Which increase if the CPU is utilized more.) Is it a server and are you worried about being able to handle new connections? Are you worried about latency in what the machine is doing? (High CPU usage potentially means higher latency.) Computer systems performance is unfortunately too broad a topic to address here, so not sure you'll get a good answer to such a general question...

Comment: top does. It shows you % idle and also breaks the rest of the time in user CPU, system CPU and further categories (which also quickly go out of scope for this website.) Also note there's not something like "instant" CPU utilization, you can only measure it over an interval, typically of 1 or 2 seconds at least...

Comment: it's a Jenkins VM machine, and we want to get an alert / be aware when total CPU cross the 70% so we'll know something not good happens there and overload the machine

Comment: All the other methods should work too... They're all gathering information at the same authoritative place, which is the kernel proc interface at `/proc/stat`. Top or mpstat will format that nicely for you. But they should all essentially agree on CPU utilization (in average), since they're reading their counters from the same place.

Comment: If your tests running on Jenkins are sensitive to latency, that's reasonable. If they're not, running it at 100% shouldn't be a problem, except that tests will in average run slower (take longer) since they'll all be fighting for the same CPU resources.

Comment: so there is no diffrence between the command `(top -b -n2 -p 1 | fgrep "Cpu(s)" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix="$prefix" '{ split($1, vs, ","); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub("%", "", v); printf "%s%.1f%%\n", prefix, 100 - v }')` to `awk '{u=$2+$4; t=$2+$4+$5; if (NR==1){u1=u; t1=t;} else print ($2+$4-u1) * 100 / (t-t1) "%"; }' \
<(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) <(sleep 1;grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat)` to `mpstat | awk '$3 ~ /CPU/ { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /%idle/) field=i } } $3 ~ /all/ { print 100 - $field }'` ? all give the same result?

Comment: I just want to know the right command for seeing when the total CPU pass 70% out of 100%